# How do you change the coordinates in a loop?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to create a row of numbers in python turtle, similar to something like this, with spaces between each number:
`0     1     2     3     4     5     6     8     9`

This is my code so far in a loop:

```
import turtle

pen = turtle.Turtle()
numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
coordinates = 100,100
for i in range(10):
  pen.penup()
  pen.goto(coordinates)
  pen.pendown()
  pen.write(numbers[i])
  coordinates = coordinates
```

Whenever I run this, it writes the numbers 0-9, but in the same spot at the coordinates 100,100.
I want each number to be 50 apart, so after the number 0 is at 100,100 the number 1 should be at 100,150. So, at the very end, what would I put after the "coordinates word" so that each number would be 50 apart?

Comment: Have you tried something like `+ 50 * int(numbers[i])` as an additive to your Y coordinate?

Comment: You should use `for number in numbers:` instead of using a range.

Comment: Since it is a list of characters, it can be even more simplified to `for number in "0123456789":`. But the real problem is that `coordinates` are NOT being updated inside the loop.

Comment: To update coordinates to be fifty apart, your last line should look something like this: `coordinates = (coordinates[0], coordinates[1] + 50)`.  Alternatively, you can get rid of `coordinates` and use `pen.goto((100, 100 + 50*i))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you write each number, the coordinate needs to be updated as well.

In your last line `coordinates = coordinates`, you could try

```
coordinates = (coordinates[0], coordinates[1] + 50)
```

So that the y value is updated by 50 with each iteration.